# Opera - something terrible with focus and hover events

Tags: html, css, opera

I have some CSS that works well in Chrome, FireFox, and IE, but looks very strange in Opera.

Link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKvqM/)

Also, I took screenshots:

This what happens on just forgot link hover:

[image]

This happens on form focus (complete disaster):

[image]

Normal look in Chrome:

[image]

1. Submit button on focus loses it's border color (why in hell?!)
2. Some mess on focus, I can't explain, just take a look on second pic

I tested on the latest version of Opera. What the hell is wrong with this browser? Even IE8 shows everything as I expect it.

CSS:

```
.sign_in {

    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -255px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 510px ;
    height: 240px;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px  black;
    box-shadow:         0 0 5px  black;


}
.signs_form{
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-color:  rgba(80, 140, 255, 0.83);
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    vertical-align: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;




}

input#email{

    border-style: solid;
    border-color:  #378de5;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;


}
input#email:focus{
    border-color: rgba(2, 22, 222, 0.97);

}
input#password{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:  #378de5;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;

}

input#password:focus{
    border-color: rgba(2, 22, 222, 0.97);

}




.sign_in_submit {
    margin-top: 0;
    border: solid 1px #378de5;;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #378de5;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px ;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;


}
.sign_in_submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: rgba(2, 22, 222, 0.97);
    color: rgba(2, 22, 222, 0.97);
}


#close {

    float: right;
    padding-left:-10px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 5px;


}
#close_sign_in_popup {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #d61354;
}

#close_sign_in_popup:hover {
    color: #fc145f;
}
.forgot_pass{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    color: #378de5;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.forgot_pass:hover{
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Post a picture of what it looks like normally.  It looks to me like you've got content overlapping.  Most browsers can handle this, as it will just ignore your settings and mash everything together (more or less).   Apparently, not Opera.

Comment: added chrome screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Forked http://jsfiddle.net/w29WQ/1/

```
.sign_in {
    /*top: 50%;  // so it seems the positioning gets all funky in opera
    left: 50%;*/
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    /* Your other styles for this element */
}
```

Anyhow, seems your fixed positioning was causing errors, I simply commented out the top and left positioning in the containing div, and reset the margins to keep the element displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys.

1) Shifts in form

The reason is that Opera strongly dislikes `inline-block` as form property, which is quite logical, actually, but all other browser undertand this and it is convinient

2) Loosing border-color of submit button on field focus

But here - Opera bug, can be fixed by placing before real tag invisible copy - so it is like bait to this Opera bug.